# WordCloud from data frame with frequency python

Tags: python, word-cloud

i have a dataframe as bellow

```
Int64Index: 14830 entries, 25791 to 10668
Data columns (total 2 columns):
word    14830 non-null object
coef    14830 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
```

i try to make word cloud with coef as a frequency instead count
for ample

```
text = df['word']
WordCloud.generate_from_text(text)
TypeError: generate_from_text() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

or

```
text = np.array(df['word'])
WordCloud.generate_from_text(text)
TypeError: generate_from_text() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

How can i improve this code & made word cloud like this

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
wordcloud = WordCloud( ranks_only= frequency).generate(text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

thanks

Comment: That's not how an answer should be made public on stack overflow. It's better to write an answer of your own, and not have it as part of your question. You can even accept your own answer to mark the question as solved.

Comment: @MERose thanx I've done it

Comment: Great! You should also be able to accept your answer, possibly after a short waiting time.

Comment: @Edward, did you solve your problem?

Comment: [Edward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5998425/edward) is my answer below correct? did it help you?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For me it worked creating a dictionary, like this:

```
d = {}
for a, x in bag.values:
    d[a] = x

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

wordcloud = WordCloud()
wordcloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies=d)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

where `bag` is a pandas DataFrame with columns **words** and **counts**

Comment: The loop on top is the key for this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

first we get list of tuples

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
```

then

```
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(dict(tuples))
```

that's all

Comment: I tried this, and I'm getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`. Did you have any issues with this?

Comment: @zanahorias Convert the tuples to dict using dict(tuples) and pass it will work.
"""
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(dict(tuples))