# Generate Wordcloud from a dataset, using only one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, word-cloud

I try to create a word cloud from a dataset

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from os import path
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline
```

Then I read combined the file

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("Aug.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("Jul.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv("Jun.csv")
df4 = pd.read_csv("Sep.csv")
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4])
```

Extract summary column ONLY

```
dfs = df['summary']
```

Generate word cloud

```
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(dfs)
```

Error came out

**TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**

I have searched for a solution, but none of the answers or resources solve my problem...

May I ask why this is happening, and possibly have a solution? Many thanks!!!

I am using Jupyter Notebook

My data type looks like

```
id    listing_url   name                   summary
123   https:1       hello python Apple     Find this please. Hello bbb / 1IDK hello......end.
456   https:2       world Boo hello        
789   https:3       python...world         My xxx 1 okay please. Just a 10-minute.......end.
```

Comment: maybe you gave a string object where a byte object was required, check this out please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47779462/typeerror-expected-string-or-bytes-like-object-python-3-wordcloud

Comment: could you post your `Aug.csv` as example please?

Comment: Yes, examples look like above.

Comment: What do you mean byte object was required? and how I can solve this issue? Thx...

Comment: I don't think wordcloud takes a pandas series as input. But rather a list of strings.

Comment: @EzrealReal: Try `wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(" ".join(dfs))`, because wordcloud needs a string as parameter. Using a space to prevent that the last word of one entry gets concatenated with the first word of the next.