# i' m trying to display a wordcloud image but I'm getting ValueError: We need at least 1 word to plot a word cloud, got 0

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]

```
frequencies={}
def iterate():
    words=file_contents.split()

    for word in words:
        if word not in uninteresting_words and word not in punctuations:
            if word not in frequencies and word in file_contents:
                frequencies[word]+=1
            else:
                frequencies[word]=1   





#wordcloud
cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
cloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies)
return cloud.to_array()




  myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
  plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest')
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()
```

Comment: update your question with the exact error you get.

Comment: i get error ValueError: We need at least 1 word to plot a word cloud, got 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this library, so if this doesn't work feel free to let me know.

For one, this if statement appears to be flipped:

```
        if word not in frequencies and word in file_contents:
            frequencies[word]+=1
        else:
            frequencies[word]=1
```

Switch it to

```
if word in frequencies and word in file_contents:
...
```

Next, you never call the `iterate` function to populate the frequencies. Do this before the wordcloud is called.

Finally, [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465478/wordcloud-from-data-frame-with-frequency-python) put in the text as such:

`wordcloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies=frequencies)`

Hopefully after doing these things it will work.

Comment: i am trying to add word to frequencies from file_contents without punctuations and without uninteresting_words

Comment: I understand, but the condition inside of `word not in uninteresting_words and word not in punctuations` should be reversed.