# How to create a word cloud based on a price (number) of each word?

Tags: python

I would like to generate a word cloud from a DataFrame with 2 columns, the first are the items and the second the prices. I'm doing the DataFrame this way:

```
articules=["Smartphone", "Laptop", "Tablet", "Headphone", "Workstation", "TV"]
votes=["900", "2000", "1000", "300", "2500", "3000"]
data={'Items': articules, 'Votes': votes}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have imported the `pandas`, `matplotlib`, and `WordCloud` libraries.
And I'm generating the word cloud this way:

```
text=' '.join(articules)
wc=WordCloud().generate(text)
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I know that WordCloud generates a word cloud based on the word frequencies, or that's what I found.
Is there a way to generate the word cloud based on the price of each item? I mean, the biggest word has the highest price and the smallest word, the lowest price.
But I'm new using Python, it's only a project from my class so I don't know this language in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_from_frequencies`. For details see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43108642/327165